# react-draft-wysiwyg propagating onBlur event

Tags: react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using react-draft-wysiwyg along with a MUI button.
react-draft-wysiwyg onBlur is being called when clicking on the Button (this is good), yet the event does not propagate to the button (this is bad).

Banging my head, any ideas?